# What is Windows Automatic Maintenance? and How can I manually disable it?

Tags: performance, ssd, windows-8.1, automation, maintenance

It really frustrates me and I can't disable it! Automatic Maintenance seems to take forever and reaches 80% in CPU usage or more, if it's ran automatically it stops as soon as I touch the Touchpad but if I run it manually it'll never finishes!

What does it do exactly and is it necessary for it to be enabled to let Windows 8.1 Pro's Optimize Drive feature TRIM my SSD regularly ? I hope Automatic Maintenance does not try to Defragment anyway, because that'd be stupid considering Optimize Drive (previously called : Disk Defrag) is AWARE that I'm using an SSD and uses TRIM instead.

Also, is there a way to disable Automatic Maintenance anyway, it really frustrates me in the night when the fan starts spinning too loud when I leave the computer on. I'm a power user and I run Windows Update and can clean my computer manually.

**UPDATE:** I'm also asking whether one of Automatic Maintenance tasks is defragmenting directly or it'll execute the "Optimize Drive" application ? this is an important thing.

**UPDATE:** I am still looking for an answer and solution to this problem! I believe it's not a duplicate because I "Disable “automatic maintenance” in Windows 8" does NOT work, therefore a solution has yet to be found for disabling this "Automatic Maintenance" thing, which is still annoying me everyday when I leave my computer standby for lunch.

Comment: Because its automatic schedule doesn't suit me. Please contribute to the core issue constructively and don't ruin the thread.

Comment: I will have a look at this right away, thank you.